# angularjs routing from one app to another

Tags: angularjs

We are developing an angularjs application in which we have two ng-apps .   When we submitform in first app 'firstApp' it should route to another app 'secondApp'. Essentillay one app before login and another app after login.

```
          The reason to have different app is , home page after login will a role based MENU .
```

Is there a way to have sperate route files  for .config()  and have routing.

Botsrapping one app into another app, can it provide any solution ?

THANKS in advance.

Comment: http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/ may be this will help uh...

Comment: I don't know if there is some hacky way to do what you ask but user / menu association is definatelly not a reason for creating a seperate app, maybe a user module or something.

Comment: you can redirect to another html file with window.location, and there have another app. But communication between them will be hacky (through localstorage I guess)